# passing input text to action field

Tags: html

I want to pass the input field to the form action part covering field; so it looks like /{user}/some_integer_in_field if you know what I mean.

```
<form action="<c:url value='${user}/?field'/>"
          method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="text" name="field" id="field"/>
        <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
    </form>
```

can someone help? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've only tagged HTML. What other languages are you using? I recommend you change the desired action via JavaScript, based on the user variable.

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="text" name="field" id="field"/>
    <input type="submit" value="DELETE" id="submitBtn">
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script>
    var sub = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

    // When sub is clicked, compare user var
    sub.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        if(user == 1){
            // Perform post action 1
        }else if(user == 2){
            // Perform post action 2
        }
        // etc...
    });
</script>
```

You'll have to change the `user` variable as the field changes as well.

Comment: don't understand what you're trying to do here.